# Creating Map using withDefault causing null when putting element

Tags: groovy

I'm trying to use the Groovy way of creating a `TreeMap<String, List<Data>>` with default values so I easily add data to a new list if the key isn't already present.

`TreeMap<String, List<Data>> myData = (TreeMap<String, List<Data>>) [:].withDefault { [] }`

As you can see, I have the requirement to use a `TreeMap` and `withDefault` only returns a `Map` instance, so I need to cast.

When I attempt to add a new list to the map,

`myData[newKey].add(newData)`

`myData[newKey]` is `null`. However, if I change my `Map` initilization to remove the `TreeMap` cast (and change the type to just `Map` instead of `TreeMap`), `myData[newKey].add(newData)` works as expected.

What's the reasoning for this? Can I not use `withDefault` if I cast the map?

Comment: Your `myData` does not point to an instance of `groovy.lang.MapWithDefault`.  When you add the cast or assign a `groovy.lang.MapWithDefault` to a reference of an incompatible static type (like `TreeMap`) Groovy is doing more than just imposing the runtime cast.  It is creating a whole new `Map` with the characteristics of the declared type, not necessarily the characteristics of the object which is having the cast applied to it.  In your case that means you are getting a `Map` with the characteristics of a `TreeMap`, not the characteristics of a `MapWithDefault`. See my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem isn't just about the cast.  It also has to do with the declared type.  The problem can be simplified to something like this:

```
def map1 = [:].withDefault { 0 }
TreeMap map2 = map1
```

When that is executed `map1` is an instance of `groovy.lang.MapWithDefault` and `map2` is an instance of `java.util.TreeMap`.  They are 2 separate objects on the heap, not just 2 references pointing to the same object.  `map2` will not have any default behavior associated with it.  It is as if you had done this:

```
def map1 = [:].withDefault { 0 }
TreeMap map2 = new TreeMap(map1)
```

That is what is happening with your code.  The cast and the generics just makes it less clear with your code.

This:

```
TreeMap<String, List<Data>> myData = (TreeMap<String, List<Data>>) [:].withDefault { [] }
```

Can be broken down to this:

```
def tmpMap = [:].withDefault { [] }
TreeMap<String, List<Data>> myData = (TreeMap<String, List<Data>>)tmpMap
```

I hope that helps.

**EDIT:**

Another way to see the same thing happening is to do something like this:

```
Set names = new HashSet()
ArrayList namesList = names
```

When the second line executes a new ArrayList is created as if you had done `ArrayList namesList = new ArrayList(names)`.  That looks different than what you have in your code, but the same sort of thing is happening.  You have a reference with a static type associated with it and are pointing that reference at an object of a different type and Groovy is creating an instance of your declared type.  In this simple example above, that declared type is `ArrayList`.  In your example that declared type is `TreeMap<String, List<Data>>`.

Comment: Okay, so it sounds like it's not possible then to use a `TreeMap` when using `Map.withDefault`.

Comment: That is right.  You can have a `TreeMap` or you can have a `MapWithDefault` but no object can be both because those are both concrete classes.  This is kind of an unfortunate implementation detail, but that is how it is at the moment.  You could come up with your own `Map` implementation that had both behaviors if you wanted to go to that trouble.  That wouldn't be terribly difficult to do.

Comment: Very good, thanks for the thorough explanation. I think I'l just avoid using `withDefault` in this instance. I was just trying to make use of some syntactic sugar but that benefit gets lost if I need to start making my own `Map` implementation to use it :)